# Changing HTML page Icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icons

I have a webpage. I want to change the icon on button down *(this would be enough for me to understand but I'd be glad if you'd describe a way to animate icon after button click)*.

Comment: Do you want to change the favicon, or something else? More detail, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do want to change the favicon, jball's solution will not work, because browsers don't seem to notice when an existing `<link>` changes.  You need to remove the existing tag and insert a new one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#favicon').remove();
    $('head').append('<link href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon">');
});
```

NB This supposes that your original favicon link has the id `favicon`.

Comment: Looks like you're right about needing to insert the new one. I would still use `$("#favicon")` instead of  `$('link[rel=shortcut icon]')` unless there's some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: @jball So would I -- changed.  Thanks.

Comment: We can change the favicon more than on time? not only when ready, like, whena  message popups change the favicon? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/click/

check this for click event . In that demo , remove class is using.
addClass function is there.

You can change image using css itself if you want.

show() hide(); functions are there to show hide divs . you can use these too